# How to convert var in List?

Tags: c#, struct, var

I need to convert a `var` in the type `List<myStruct>`.
I had to use `var` to order a list of `myStruct` and I got `orderedList2`, but now I need to iterate this list and I don't know how to do it.

```
public struct myStruct
{

    public String delivery;
    public String articleCode;
    public String dex;
    public String phase;
    public String quantity;

};

List<myStruct> myList;

var orderedList2 = myList.OrderByDescending(x =>
    {
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParse(x.delivery, out dt);
        return x;
    });

// now I have to fill the ListView again
foreach(myStruct str in orderedList2)
{
    string[] s = new string[5];
    s[0] = str.delivery;
    s[1] = str.articleCode;
    s[2] = str.dex;
    s[3] = str.phase;
    s[4] = str.quantity;

    ListViewItem itl = new ListViewItem(s);
    ////String s = r["DEXART"].ToString();
    ////MessageBox.Show(s);
    listView1.Items.Add(itl);
}
```

When the code hits the `foreach` statement I get an exception.

Comment: "When the code hit the foreach statement I got an exception." Can you add the Exception details?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert var"?  If you're getting an error, *read the error*.  It's telling you what's wrong.

Comment: do you ever assign anything to the myList variable?

Comment: A side note: from your question I can see that you do not understand the var keyword I suggest you read about it more.

Comment: @MindSwipe sorry it's in italian "System.ArgumentException: 'Almeno un oggetto deve implementare IComparable.'" but it basically says the at least one object must implement IComparable

Comment: You are trying to order by your struct 'myStruct' you return it in ordering lambda.

Comment: @David I want orderedList2 to be a List<myStruct>

Comment: @Andreas yeas I checked it contains elements

Comment: @Ale61268967: It's already an `IEnumerable<myStruct>`.  If it *needs* to be a `List<myStruct>` (and it doesn't) then just add `.ToList()` after the `.OrderByDescending()` call.  But, if you read and look up the error message, that's *not* your problem.

Comment: @Ale61268967: *"I checked it contains elements"* - Not according to the code you're showing us.  This code would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: OT a `struct` with mutable fields is a bad idea. Why not use a `class`?

Comment: Are you really sure that `delivery` shouldn't be a DateTime to start with? And `quantity` should probably be an integer or double.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either implement IComparable on your struct or you have a mistake in your order lambda:

```
 var orderedList2 = myList.OrderByDescending(x =>
    {
        DateTime dt;
       if( DateTime.TryParse(x.delivery, out dt))
           return dt;
        return DateTime.MinValue;
    });
```

you can follow it with `.ToList()` cal to get `List<myStruct> orderedList2`.

---

it works:

[image]

Comment: I do still get the "IComparable" exception when trying to do this

Comment: @Ale61268967 no, you would not.

Comment: @Ale61268967 "I do still get the IComparable exception". You probably have skipped the "implement IComparable on your struct" step of the answer.

Comment: its either or, you either implement the IComparable as presented by Stefan in other answer or implement OrderByDescending as shown above, and you do not want to do the IComparable. Just copy and paste my code It works. And do not use structs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to make your struct a class (delcare it outside your current class) and implement `IComparable` like so:

```
public class myClass : IComparable
{
    public String delivery;
    public String articleCode;
    public String dex;
    public String phase;
    public String quantity;

    // Order by delivery datetime
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(myClass ) || (obj.delivery == delivery))
            return 0;

        DateTime dtDelivery = DateTime.ParseExact(delivery, "dd-MM-yyyy");
        DateTime dtObjDelivery = DateTime.ParseExact((obj as myClass).delivery, "dd-MM-yyyy");
        return dt.Delivery.CompareTo(dtObjDelivery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instansiate the list so:

```
List<myStruct> myList;
```

Should be

```
List<myStruct> myList = new List<myStruct>;
```

Without this I belive that myList would be null. Hence the null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var orderedList2 = myList.OrderByDescending(x =>
    {
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParse(x.delivery, out dt);
        return x;
    });
```

you are returning "x", which is a `myStruct`. And you are ignoring the `dt` that you just parsed (without checking whether that succeeded, also).

So for a quick fix of this part, just `return dt;` to order by "delivery" as date (assuming it always does contain a parsable date).